# MERN stack and Socket to Mongodb - real time data to frontend from database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, sockets, mern

I am setting up a website with MERN stack. in the backend I will be constantly fetching data from api/socket and saving that to the Mongodb database. Now the frontend React I want to real-time show/update data with Socket.

I am a bit worried about the amount of request/connections the server side and Mongodb can handle.
Its not clear how to setup a proper system to handle millions of users.

If someone can give me some info on what, how and/or where to search on how to setup a stable system.

Any info is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a suggestion for the MongoDB portion.

You may want to try out their official course on MongoDB to understand how their transaction works. [MongoBD University](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/catalog), for hands-on try their "MongoDB for JavaScript Developers" course.

Here are some things to look out for:

1. Connection Pooling
2. Understand how transactions work
3. Indexes, especially on how to create a good one like following the ESR
4. MongoDB Clusters, Write into primary and read from secondary

I will update the list if I have time and remember some of the stuff.

Comment: Many many thanks, this is already a good start. I won't accept your answer as I would like more info. hope that's ok.

Comment: that is okay, this is a suggestion